# Ruby: If last variable was saved more than 3 hours ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby form to submit reports for an exercise on my app.  An exercise `has_many` reports.  I want to create an if statement that makes this form only appear if the last report from that exercise was saved more than 3 hours ago.

So far I have:

But this is creating a `NoMethodError` saying `undefined method 'report' for #<Exercise:0x007f9c892f48b0>`.

It's being displayed on my `workouts#show` page (a workout `has_many` exercises, in case it helps), so I believe this is the reigning controller:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

This bit is technically on my `workouts#show` page:

```
<% if @workout.exercises.count == 0 %>
        <p>Looks like you get a freebie for this one!  No score report today.  Rest up and drink some water.  It ain't always that easy...</p>
      <% else %>
        <% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>
          <%= render 'reports/form', report: @report, exercise: exercise %>
          <% if current_user.admin? %>
            <div class="text-center"><%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", [exercise], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></div>
          <% end %>
          <hr>
        <% end %>
```

But here is the partial it renders, where the code in question actually lies:

```
<% if exercise.report.last != nil && exercise.report.last.created_at < ( DateTime.now - (3/24.0)) %>

<%= form_for report,
  :url => { :controller => "reports",
  :action => :create,
  :exercise_id => exercise.id } do |f| %>
<div class="row">

...
```

Comment: Can you paste the code from your show view? It seems like you might be calling `@exercise.report` which does not exist?

Comment: Whats in yr show html page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you calling singularized `report` instead of `reports`.

```
if exercise.report.last
```

If reports relates to exercise as `has_many` you need to call it with `exercise.reports.last`

Also, you mentioned `results` in your question, but calling `reports` in your view.

> An exercise has_many results.

...

> exercise.report.last

Please be sure you calling appropriate pluralize method `reports` or `results`

Comment: Those darn plurals!  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Welcome :)